# Persist /etc/environment variables to non interactive user

Tags: linux, redhat, systemd, rhel7

**Testing OS:** RHEL7

**Required OSs**: RHEL & Derivatives & AIX

I have a user that was created as follows:

```
sudo groupadd madt
sudo useradd -r -g madt -s /bin/false madt
```

That user is being used in a `systemd` service as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=MicroStrategy Mobile Access Distribution Tool
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=madt
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/pandera/mobile-registration/mobile-access-distribution-tool-1.0.0.jar --spring.config.location=/opt/pandera/mobile-registration/
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The java app requires that an environment variable be present. I've set the variable in `/etc/environment` and confirmed that it works for root and all other interactive users.

**How can I get the madt user to recognize my environment variable?**

Comment: why you don't use Environment system directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EnvironmentFile](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.directives.html#EnvironmentFile=%22EnvironmentFile=%22) line in your systemd unit.

For example

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
```

Systemd will then read your file and inject variables from file to your program's environment.

If you need to set only single environment variable only for this system unit, just use

```
Environment=VERBOSITY_LEVEL=1
```